# Trouble with working out the angle of from player to cursor in pygame

Tags: python, vector, pygame, trigonometry

So I'm trying to make the game asteroids but are having trouble with working out the angle of which the spacecraft should look in. I know the basics of trigonometry but with the y-axis flipped I'm getting a bit confused. I've made a mockup of the problem so you don't have to look through the whole code.

```
import pygame
import sys
import math

DIMENSIONS = (600, 600)
window = pygame.display.set_mode(DIMENSIONS, pygame.RESIZABLE)
window.fill((20, 20, 20))
pygame.display.set_caption("Pygame template")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

player_pos = pygame.Vector2(275,275)
player = pygame.Rect(player_pos.xy, (50,50))

looking_vector = pygame.Vector2(1,1)

while True:

    window.fill((20,20,20))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    player = pygame.Rect(player_pos.xy, (50,50))

    # Relative position of mouse
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    delta = mouse_pos - player_pos
    
    # Calculate the angle 
    angle_to_mouse = math.atan2(delta.y, delta.x)
    looking_vector.xy = (100*math.cos(angle_to_mouse), 100*math.sin(angle_to_mouse))
    
    # Player rect
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (50, 50, 255), player)
    # Line to mouse
    pygame.draw.line(window, (255,50,50), player_pos + (25,25), pygame.mouse.get_pos())
    # Line in direction to looking_vector
    pygame.draw.line(window, (50,255,50), player_pos + (25,25), player_pos + looking_vector)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

[image: Demonstration of the problem]

As you can see in the image above the red line - which is only a line between the center of the rectangle and the mouse position - is completely fine but when it comes to the green line it is a bit off.

This is pretty much the effect I get in my asteroid game only that it's pretty much fine if the player stays close to the axes. However if the player moves further away from either one of them the effect amplifies and the looking vector is completely in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm works fine. However, you need to use the center of the player to calculate the angle instead of the top left corner of the player:

```py
player = pygame.Rect(player_pos.xy, (50,50))
player_center = pygame.Vector2(player.center)

# Relative position of mouse
mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
delta = mouse_pos - player_center

# Calculate the angle 
angle_to_mouse = math.atan2(delta.y, delta.x)
looking_vector.xy = (100*math.cos(angle_to_mouse), 100*math.sin(angle_to_mouse))

# Player rect
pygame.draw.rect(window, (50, 50, 255), player)
# Line to mouse
pygame.draw.line(window, (255,50,50), player_center, pygame.mouse.get_pos())
# Line in direction to looking_vector
pygame.draw.line(window, (50,255,50), player_center, player_center + looking_vector)
```

[image]